# Unable to find type [WinSCP.EnumerateOptions]

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm working with WinSCP in PowerShell to manage files in a FTP. In using the standard script given on the WinSCP website, I am getting this error:

> Unable to find type [WinSCP.EnumerateOptions].

[image]

I am working in version 5.13 - fresh off the site.

```
$remotePath = "ftp://username:password@network:port/relevantfolder/"
$localPath = "C:/Users/me/localdir"
$mask = "*.*"

$files = EnumerateRemoteFiles(
             $remotePath, $mask, [WinSCP.EnumerateOptions]::AllDirectories)

foreach ($fileInfo in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Downloading $($fileInfo.FullName) ..."
    $filePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($fileInfo.FullName)
    $session.GetFiles($filePath, $localPath + "\*").Check() 
}
```

Comment: A quick aside: There's also a PowerShell-friendly wrapper for WinSCP (created by a different developer): https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WinSCP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's [`EnumerationOptions`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles#options), not `EnumerateOptions`.
2. [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) is a method, so you need to call it on [`Session` instance](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session).
3. The [`path` argument of `Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles#path) is a **path**, not an URL:

   ```
   $remotePath = "/relevantfolder/"
   ```

Comment: Thank you - everything is working now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* [Martin Prikryl's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53674692/45375):

Your problem came down to **misremembering the type name**, which in PowerShell doesn't surface until *runtime*.

You can **mitigate the problem with PowerShell's *tab completion*,** however:

```
[winscp.enumerate<tab> # NO completion, because no such type exists.

[winscp.enumeration<tab> # -> completion to [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]
```

Note that completion **even works without a namespace component** (e.g., `[enumerationo<tab>]`), but with short or common name prefixes there can be many matches to cycle through.

Conversely, **if completion does *not* occur**, the **possible causes** are:

- The assembly implementing the target type isn't loaded into the session yet.

  - Use `Add-Type -Path` / `Add-Type -AssemblyName` to load it or `Import-Module`, if it comes with a module.
- You've mistyped the type name (prefix).

  - Experiment with variants using tab completion or consult the docs.